# AWS lambda with dynamic trigger for S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a S3 bucket by name "archive_A". I have created a lambda function to retrieve meta data info for any object "creation" or "permanently delete" from S3 bucket as triggers to my lambda function (python) and insert the meta data collected into DynamoDB.
For S3 bucket archive_A, I have manually added the triggers, one for "creation" and another one for "permanently delete" in my lambda function via GUI.

```
import boto3
from uuid import uuid4
def lambda_handler(event, context):
        s3 = boto3.client("s3")
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
        for record in event['Records']:
                bucket_name = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
                object_key = record['s3']['object']['key']
                size = record['s3']['object'].get('size', -1)
                event_name = record ['eventName']
                event_time = record['eventTime']
                dynamoTable = dynamodb.Table('S3metadata')
                dynamoTable.put_item(
                          Item={'Resource_id': str(uuid4()), 'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Object': object_key,'Size': size, 'Event': event_name, 'EventTime': event_time})
```

In the future there could be more S3 buckets like archive_B, archive_C etc. In that case I have to keep adding triggers manually for each S3 bucket which is bit cumbersome.

Is there any dynamic way or adding triggers to lambda for S3 buckets with name "archive_*" and hence any future S3 bucket with name like "archive_G" will have a dynamically added triggers to lambda.

Please suggest. I am quite new to AWS too. Any example would be easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-built way to automatically add triggers for new buckets.

You could probably create an **Amazon EventBridge rule** that triggers on `CreateBucket` and calls an AWS Lambda function with details of the new bucket.

That Lambda function could then programmatically add a trigger on your existing Lambda function.

[image: Amazon EventBridge rule]